# WPF: How to upload an image to your project and use it later on as a resource

Tags: c#, wpf, image-uploading

I'm studying WPF at school but I ran into a problem with uploading a new image to my project.

The goal is to be able to add an image (at runtime) using a file browser. This image should be uploaded into the project and the filename should be saved in a database. Than it should be accessible as a resource in the project so I can show the image in a listbox for example.

This is what I've got so far:

View where the upload happens:

```
    <Image Height="70px" Source="{Binding newImg}"/>
    <Button Height="23" Name="btnLoad" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
    Width="75" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding ImgUploadCommand}">_Browse</Button>
```

ViewModel UploadView

```
    private string fullPath; 
    private BitmapImage image;
    private Patient newPatient = new Patient();

    private void KoppelenCommands()
    {
        FotoUploadCommand = new BaseCommand(FotoPatientUpload);
        PatientOpslaanCommand = new BaseCommand(PatientOpslaan);
    }

    public ICommand FotoUploadCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand PatientOpslaanCommand { get; set; }

    public void FotoPatientUpload()
    {
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.Title = "Select a picture";
        op.Filter = "All supported graphics|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|" +
          "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg)|*.jpg;*.jpeg|" +
          "Portable Network Graphic (*.png)|*.png";
        if (op.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            image= new BitmapImage(new Uri(op.FileName));
            fullPath = op.FileName;
            string[] partsFileName = fullPath.Split('\\');
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(delenFileName[(partsFileName.Length - 1)]);
            NewPatient.Image= partsFileName[(delenFileName.Length - 1)];
        }
    }

    public void PatientOpslaan()
    {

                string destinationPath = GetDestinationPath(NewPatient.Afbeelding, "\\assets\\images");

                File.Copy(fullPath, destinationPath, true);


            //dataservice (My DS works fine, I can see the correct filename in the database but I save only the name not the Path)
            PatientDataService patientDS =
               new PatientDataService();

            patientDS.InsertPatient(NewPatient);


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Niet alle velden zijn ingevuld! Een nieuwe patient moet tenminste een naam en een voornaam krijgen!", "Fout!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }


    //opslaan foto in opgegeven map <<Code afkomstig van stackoverflow auteur: Yashpal Singla>>
    private static String GetDestinationPath(string filename, string foldername)
    {
        String appStartPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        appStartPath = String.Format(appStartPath + "\\{0}\\" + filename, foldername);
        return appStartPath;
    }
```

The image is correctly saved to the bin/debug/assets/images folder but not as a resource. Because it isn't saved as a resource I can't use it in my MainWindow View which looks like this:

```
                <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Patienten}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPatient}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Name="ImageNameListBox" Visibility="Collapsed"  
                                    Text="{Binding Image, StringFormat=../assets/images/{0}}" />
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource imageBorderStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Height="80px" Width="80px">
                            <Rectangle Margin="1,-2,-2,1" Height="80px" Width="80px">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Text, ElementName=ImageNameListBox}"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

MainWindow ViewModel:

```
    class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    private DialogService dialogService;
    private ObservableCollection<Patient> patienten;

    public ObservableCollection<Patient> Patienten
    {
        get
        {
            return patienten;
        }

        set
        {
            patienten = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private Patient selectedPatient;
    public Patient SelectedPatient {get; set;}
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        LoadingPatients();


        //instantiëren DialogService als singleton
        dialogService = new DialogService();
    }

    private void LoadingPatients()
    {
        //instantiëren dataservice
        PatientDataService patientDS =
           new PatientDataService();

        Patienten = new ObservableCollection<Patient>(patientDS.GetPatienten());
    }
    }
```

Note that I didn't include all of the code so my datacontext is set with a ViewModelLocator which you cannot see here.

Is there any way to save the image as a resource or do I have to convert all the images in the /bin/debug/assets/images folder to a resource at startup? If so how do I do that?

Apologies for my English, I'm not a native speaker

Thanks for those who had the courage to read all the way to this line and thanks for those who can and will help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the Image as `ImageSource` from your file and bind it to an `Image` in your view.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public void LoadImage()
    {
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("assets/images/yourImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

```
  <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"></Image>
```

---

As answer to the comment, this works also inside a listbox.

The **View**:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyImages}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageSource}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

The **ViewModel**:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public void LoadImages()
    {
        var d = new DirectoryInfo("assets/images");
        var images = d.GetFiles();
        MyImages = images.Select(x => new MyImageModel(x.Name, new BitmapImage(new Uri(x.FullName))));
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyImageModel> MyImages { get; set; }
}
```

The **MyImageModel**

```
public class MyImageModel
{
    public MyImageModel(string name, ImageSource imageSource)
    {
        Name = name;
        ImageSource = imageSource;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I believe this will work for a single patient object however I also need it in a listbox. I get an ObservableCollection of Patients (which you couldn't know cause I didn't put in above, my bad) which all have a different filename as their image which I use to populate a listbox.

Comment: I've added a listbox example.

Comment: Mm well first of all let me say thanks for helping me, second I tried adding this in but the problem is that I fill my listbox with patient objects. Some of them don't have an image set so I show a default one. The solution you provided doesn't give me the oppertunity (I think) to link the image to the patient. I tried adding the model part to my PatientModel but than I don't know how to get just that image and convert it to an imageSource.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually managed to get it fixed. I used your first code to loop over all my patient objects and got all the images like that. Gives me a bit more work using the DataService but that's not really an issue. Thank you very much!